# React-Native: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: loops, react-native, input, setstate, native-base

I've the following login screen that before updating `react-native` to `0.60.4` is working fine.

```
interface OwnProps {
    navigation: any
}

interface StateProps {
    isLoggedIn: boolean,
    isAuthenticating: boolean
}

interface DispatchProps {
    actions: {
        auth: {
            authenticate: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<void>
        }
    }
}

type Props = OwnProps & StateProps & DispatchProps
interface State {
    username: string,
    password: string,
    error?: string,
    fadeAnim: Animated.Value
}

class LoginScreen extends Component<Props, State> {
    static propTypes = {
        isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        isAuthenticating: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        actions: PropTypes.shape({
            auth: PropTypes.object
        })
    }

    state: State = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        error: null,
        fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1)
    }

    keyboardDidShowListener: EmitterSubscription
    keyboardDidHideListener: EmitterSubscription

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this._onLogin = this._onLogin.bind(this)
        this._handleUsernameChange = this._handleUsernameChange.bind(this)
        this._handlePasswordChange = this._handlePasswordChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow)
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        this.setState({
            username: '',
            password: null,
            error: null,
            fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1)
        })

        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove()
    }

    _keyboardDidShow = (): void => {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.fadeAnim,
            {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 500
            }
        ).start()
    }

    _keyboardDidHide = (): void => {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.fadeAnim,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 500
            }
        ).start()
    }

    _onLogin = (): void => {
        dismissKeyboard()

        if (this.isFormValid()) {
            this.props.actions.auth.authenticate(this.state.username, this.state.password)
                .catch((error: Error) => {
                    const message: string = error ? error.message : 'Si e\' verificato un errore.'
                    this.setState({ error: message })
                    Toast.error(error.message)
                })
        }
    }

    isFormValid(): boolean {
        this.setState({ error: null })

        if (!this.state.username || this.state.username === '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Username non valido.' })
            Toast.error('Username non valido.')
            return false
        }

        if (!this.state.password || this.state.password === '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Password non valida.' })
            Toast.error('Password non valida.')
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    _handleUsernameChange = (username: string) => {
        this.setState({ username })
    }

    _handlePasswordChange = (password: string) => {
        this.setState({ password })
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        const { fadeAnim } = this.state

        return (
            <Content
                padder
                style={styles.content}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
            >
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={dismissKeyboard}>
                    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                        <Spinner visible={this.props.isAuthenticating} textContent={'Accesso in corso...'} textStyle={{color: 'white'}} />

                        <Animated.View style={[styles.logosContainer, { opacity: fadeAnim }]}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.logo}
                                source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
                            />
                        </Animated.View>

                        <Form style={styles.form}>
                            <Item floatingLabel error={this.state.error ? true : false}>
                                <Label>Username</Label>
                                <Input
                                    autoCapitalize='none'
                                    autoCorrect={false}
                                    value={this.state.username}
                                    onChangeText={this._handleUsernameChange}
                                />
                            </Item>
                            <Item floatingLabel error={this.state.error ? true : false}>
                                <Label>Password</Label>
                                <Input
                                    autoCapitalize='none'
                                    autoCorrect={false}
                                    secureTextEntry
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChangeText={this._handlePasswordChange}
                                />
                            </Item>
                        </Form>

                        {/*this.state.error ? (<FormMessage message={this.state.error} />) : null*/}

                        <Button block success style={styles.loginButton} onPress={this._onLogin}>
                            <Text>Accedi</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Content>
        )
    }
}

[...]

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

After the update, when I try to input username or password, the following expection is thrown:

> Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I've read many questions here on stack overflow and around the internet but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillUnmount()` is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in `componentDidMount()`.

You should not call `setState()` in `componentWillUnmount()` because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

You can remove `setState()` in `componentWillUnmount()`

```js
    componentWillUnmount(): void {

        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this not solves the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but after upgraded to the latest `react-navigation` version all works fine again.